# EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE not functional?

Tags: presto

Despite being listed in the documentation:

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/explain-analyze.html

The `VERBOSE` tag for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` doesn't appear to work (tested on `0.187`):

```
explain analyze verbose
select * from (
  values ('blah', 1, 2), ('blue', 2, 3)
) example_table("test", "start", "end")
```

> SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#1): line 1:17: no viable alternative at input 'verbose'

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` without `VERBOSE` works fine.

Is there a `dev_mode` option I need to activate perhaps? Or am I just using the syntax wrong?

Comment: The error message says you wrote **verbsoe**, not **verbose**

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen whoops; although, same error even after typo correction

Comment: Are you sure you're running this against Presto? Your query pasted verbatim into Presto 0.210 works as expected, but I don't recall any problems with EXPLAIN in the past.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen It's against `0.187`, and I checked the documentation to be sure the `VERBOSE` tag was available there as well: https://prestodb.io/docs/0.187/sql/explain-analyze.html

Comment: `VERBOSE` functionality was added per the dox in `0.181`: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.181.html

Comment: Strange. Would you mind trying this out on some newer version?

Comment: Not in my control but I think we're updating soon. Anyway will follow-up if/when